# Is there a way to simplify $a\log(b) +\log(c)$?

Tags: logarithms

> Very simply: 
>   $$a\log(b) +\log(c)$$

The coefficient on the first term is throwing me off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the properties 
$$a \log b = \log b^a$$ and
$$\log a +\log b = \log ab.$$
Thus
$$a\log b +\log c = \log b^a+\log c = \log(b^ac).$$

Answer (score 2):

You can write $a\log(b) +\log(c)=\log(b^ac).$ Past that, there's not a lot we can do.

Comment: Yup, sorry. Copy and pasting isn't working for me! Should be fixed now!